# How can I mark a method `required`

Tags: swift, swift5

In swift, I can mark an intializer as `required`, so that derived classes have to override it. How can I do the same for a normal instance method ? Marking it as `required` throws a compiler error.

```
class A {
  let a : Int
  required init(a:a) {
    self.a = a
  }
  // compiler error
  required func f() -> Int {
     return 2
  }
}
```

The only solution I could think of is to do this:

```
func f() -> Int {
  fatalError("Should always be overriden")
}
```

but it is unsatisfactory, as it is a runtime check and not a compile-time one.

Comment: A *required* init method does not mean that the method must be overridden in subclasses. It means only that the method is the *designated initializer* and must be used to create an instance. The `fatalError` way is the only way to force a subclass to override the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality does not exist in Swift.

You cannot force a subclass to override a method.

### However...

You say this is the best code you can find to achieve what you want, but you don't like the error being moved at runtime.

```
func f() -> Int {
    fatalError("Should always be overriden")
}
```

Looking at this method it seems you want to force a subclass to **implement** (not override) a method.

### Abstract Class

You are maybe looking for something similar to the concept of Abstract Class available in other programming languages.

### Base Class + Protocol

If this is what you are looking for, then you can achieve something similar in Swift.

```
class AnimalBase {

    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

}

protocol Animal: AnimalBase {
    func move()
}
```

Now if you try to define a class like this

```
class Dog: Animal {

}
```

the compiler will force you to inherit from `AnimalBase`

```
class Dog: AnimalBase, Animal {

}
```

And finally to provide an implementation for the `move()` method

```
class Dog: AnimalBase, Animal {

    func move() {
        print("")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I wanted. Not sure I agree on "you want to force a subclass to implement (not override)". In swift, it seems to me that override means reimplementing in the derived class, and this has the effect of overriding the parent's implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding what `required` means. `required` doesn't force you to override a initializer, it requires that an initializer *exists*.

Initializers are not always inherited. For example, if you create a new designated initializer, then the superclass ininitializers won't be inherited. `required` initializer forces you to define one in that case.

This cannot happen with normal methods because they are always inherited. That's why `required` for methods does not exist.

You are looking for *abstract* (or *pure virtual* in C++) methods which is a concept that does not exist in Swift.